# DotNetNuke - Upgrading Community Edition (CE) to Enterprise Edition (EE)

Tags: dotnetnuke

I currently have a website in DNN Community Edition (version 7.3.2). I need to upgrade the website to enterprise edition. I have tried searching (read Googling) for the steps and protocols to be followed to achieve this. However, all search results, blogs and online documentation I have encountered so far seem to be pertaining to upgrading Community Edition (CE) to Professional Edition (PE) or Professional Edition (PE) to Enterprise Edition (EE). Based on my understanding, I get the feeling that I have to upgrade to Professional Edition in order to be able to upgrade to Enterprise Edition (EE).

So can anybody tell me is it possible to upgrade Community edition to Enterprise Edition straightaway OR do I have to go through the installation of Professional edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply perform the same steps as you would to upgrade to PE. No need to upgrade to PE then EE.

Backup everything (files/database)
Download the EE Upgrade package
Extract the EE Upgrade package (make sure to unblock the ZIP if you're using Windows Compression to extract)
Copy the files from the UPGRADE extraction over your existing CE location.

Side note: Probably too late, but do you really need Enterprise Edition?

Comment: I have performed all these steps. I also had a look at your video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhZQLYHTx1s&noredirect=1) on upgrading. However, when I enter the url as shown in the video, I am simply redirected to the Default page which is that it basically navigates me to the home page. Considering that video is 4 years old and few things might have changed since, is there any change in the url for the upgrade to work?

Comment: In my company, whether Enterprise Edition is needed or not is decided by powers that be. Mere mortals or rather foot soldiers (whichever you see fit) like me are not really asked for our 2 cents worth of you know what. So yeah, you're right in saying "probably too late". We already have a DNN community version in development mode and in production mode. Having acquired the license, we need to upgrade the 2 environments to enterprise edition!! That's how I landed in this soup :)

Comment: On a side note, its the url stage where I am stuck!!

Comment: If you navigate to http://mywebsite/install/install.aspx?mode=installresources you are redirected to the root of the site?

Comment: Some days are bad, really bad. Worked like a charm post-lunch session without any changes whatsoever!! Much much thanks!! Truly appreciated!!